# lvalue reference and rvalue binding

Tags: c++, binding, pass-by-reference

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void modify_nd_print_string(string&);

int main (){
 auto s = "";
 modify_nd_print_string(s);
 return 0;
}

void modify_nd_print_string(string& s){
  s.clear();
  s = "test"; 
  cout << s << endl;
 return;
}
```

In the above code, I am using `string&` as the argument type to `modify_nd_print_string()` for obvious reasons: the method modifies the string passed on to it by reference.

However, I get the following error from compiler (g++):

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:25: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::string&’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&’} to an rvalue of type ‘std::__cxx11::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’}
  modify_nd_print_string(s);
                         ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I do not understand why the argument passed to `modify_nd_print_string()` is treated as rvalue, when what is passed to the function from `main()` is an lvalue?

Can someone explain?

TIA

Comment: `s` is `const char*`, it can't be bound to `string&`, the compilers tries to convert it to a temporary `std::string(s)` that is rvalue and also can't be bound to `string&`.

Comment: Also, strings don't have to be expliclty initilaized by `= ""`, just a `string s;` will do.

Comment: [`auto s{""s};`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) or `std::string s;`